# Concatenating # to make an id

Tags: javascript

I have the following codes which append the following html dynamically to my user interface.

```
<a href =\'#\' onClick=\'scroll('+data.cid+')\'>comment</a>
```

The data.cid is retrieved via pusher.com and is an integer valye, say 428.

In the scroll function, i will need to concatenate a hashtag in front of data.cid to make it scroll to the div #428

My scroll function i basically this.

```
function scroll(cid) {

    var id = "#" + cid; 
            $.scrollTo(id) ; 

 }
```

which should be equivalent to:

```
$.scrollTo('#428') ;
```

except its not and it is not scrolling to the required div. Everything works fine if i hardcode #428 in the function like above.

Clearly there is an issue with concatenating a hashtag in front of the numerical value. Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: try use ' instead of " i.e. var id = '#' + cid;

Comment: is `cid` a number as opposed to an empty space or something?

Comment: could you `console.log` or `alert` the value of `cid`to see what it is?

Comment: Are you sure you are giving your elements IDs?

Answer (score 2):

You JS looks fine. You markup is messed up. See comments below:

```
<a href =\'#\' id =onClick=\'scroll('+data.cid+')\'>comment</a>
               ^ id=onclick=...?
```

If the markup change does not fix your issue, use `console.log` to check the value of `cid` inside `scroll()`. Chances are it's not being passed in properly. Your JS is fine as is.